# Active cell, dynamic input using Index Match in VBA

Tags: vba, dynamic, indexing, match

I am trying to smarten up the attached excel spreadsheet using vba (sorry image attached).
The sheet has a fixed value in cell D161, set at 45, Index match uses this value to return a summary of the values in the critical columns.
I have attached a couple of modules with the sheet module one searches and finds and active cell based upon the input value of D161.
I have seen a couple of examples and have become more confused than usual
My work flow is:

- select and active cell value, based upon D161’s value
- Use this cell value as the active cell
- Select the critical columns (highlighted in lt blue) based upon this
  active cell (using offset) There are 5 columns distributed through
  the array of values
- Select the columns and present them in a summary table as shown in
  array D161:K167

I have found a topic that is similar however I’m moderately puzzled as its beyond my vba experience

[Excel / VBA - Index Match function using Dynamic Ranges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16176726/excel-vba-index-match-function-using-dynamic-ranges)

My Code

```
Sub FindThisValue()

Dim varLookFor As Variant
Dim GBAnchorageRng As Range
Dim GBLapRng As Range
Dim OCAnchorageRng As Range
Dim OCLapRng As Range

varLookFor = Range("D161").Value

'Good bond cell ranges or columns
Set GBAnchorageRng = Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.Offset(6, 15))
Set GBAnchorageRng = Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.Offset(6, 15))

'Othercases (formly known as poor do not use this description bond) cell range or columns
Set OCAnchorageRng = Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.Offset(6, 26))
Set OCAnchorageRng = Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.Offset(6, 28))

On Error GoTo Handler:

'ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.
Range("B93:B148").Find(What:=varLookFor, LookAt:=x1Whole = 1).Activate

'Specify range
'Range(ActiveCell.Offset(6, 0), ActiveCell.Offset(0, 31)).Select

Exit Sub

Handler:

MsgBox ("Value not found")

End Sub
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could try this

```
Sub FindThisValue()
    Dim f As Range

    Set f = Range("B93:B148").Find(What:=Range("D161").Value, LookAt:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlValues)
    If f Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox ("Value not found")
        Exit Sub
    End If

    With Range("F161:F167")
        .Value = f.Offset(, 15).Resize(6).Value
        .Offset(, 2).Value = f.Offset(, 16).Resize(6).Value
        .Offset(, 3).Value = f.Offset(, 26).Resize(6).Value
        .Offset(, 5).Value = f.Offset(, 27).Resize(6).Value
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: f becomes the active cell, got it `.Resize(6).Value` helped show the path in the array `Resize(7).Value` captured all of the data required. Neat and makes sense.

Comment: just to point out that my code doesn't rely on any properly called `ActiveCell` while it _reference_ `Range` objects. Which is much safer!